Getting private keys corresponding public ones listed in Azure jwks_uri
I have an application registered in Azure, among its endpoints I have the one called OpenID Connect metadata document with its value looking like https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration.
Accessing the URI above returns JSON having this key-value pair:
{
  "jwks_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/discovery/v2.0/keys"
}

Following that jwks_uri I see a set of public keys with their kid, x5t, n etc. used for server-side validation of assertion, signed on client side with a private key.
Here I face two problems:

I don't know how to download the private key from Azure to use it later for signing
Even if I'd generate my own pair of private and public key and then successfully upload the public one using App Registrations > my-app > Manage > Certificates and secrets > Certificates > Upload certificate chain, the contents of jwks_uir remains intact. As a result when I sign assertion with my generated private key it fails to be validated on Azure side as no key is found for my kid


I think you have misunderstood something.
You cannot download these private keys. They are what Microsoft uses to sign tokens across all of M365, Azure etc.
Uploading a certificate credential for your app allows your app to authenticate using that private key (generating a JSON Web Token with a specific format proves Entra ID that you possess the private key).
Entra ID can then generate a token for your app based on the scope you requested (if it is allowed for your app).
If you use Entra ID, you are not the one generating tokens, Entra ID is as it is the identity provider.
You only validate tokens generated by Entra ID when your app receives a token for that app.
For validation, you only need the public key.

Thanks for answering! Uploading a certificate credential for your app allows your app to authenticate using that private key this is what I'm lucklessly trying to achieve

These pages in docs show how it works at lower level: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/certificate-credentials. Using the MSAL library makes it quite a bit easier.

Yep, looked into it and followed the manual. Particularly doing as described in the first link I get "AADSTS700027: The certificate with identifier used to sign the client assertion is not registered on application. [Reason - The key was not found.
